# DD-WRT Shell script Wifi IP and Name addition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, dd-wrt

Hello everyone I am running DD-WRT v.3.0 on my Linksys EA6500 router and I have the following script running in order to give me access to the WiFi MAC address that are currently connected to the router:

```
echo "#!/bin/ash" > /tmp/getmac.sh
echo 'echo { > /tmp/www/list.html' >>/tmp/getmac.sh
echo "for i in \$(arp | awk '{print toupper(\$4)}'); do echo \$i, >> /tmp/www/list.html; done" >>/tmp/getmac.sh
echo 'echo } >> /tmp/www/list.html' >>/tmp/getmac.sh
chmod +x /tmp/getmac.sh
/tmp/getmac.sh
```

I can visit http://192.168.1.1/user/list.html and it will show me a list of wifi MAC address that are currently connected to the router:

Example:

```
{ 01:81:18:3d:49:5e, 04:10:87:8c:47:9a, }
```

However, I would like to modify that to also include the **IP ADDRESS** and also the **NAME OF THE DEVICE**.

I found [this](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Examples#Which_IP_addresses_and_hostnames_are_used_for_wireless_clients.3F) on the DD-WRT website but when running the command and checking the directory, I do not see it anywhere.

```
 # mkdir -p /tmp/www
 while [ 1 ];
  do
  wl assoclist | awk '{print tolower($2)}' > /tmp/assocLIST
  # echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"><b>Hostnames and IP addresses of WLAN clients</b> (last update: $(date))<p>" > /tmp/www/wlan.html
  while read assocLINE
   do
     dumpleases | awk '/'"$assocLINE"'/ {print "Hostname: " $1, "MAC: " $2, "IP: " $3}'
   # echo "<br>";
        done < /tmp/assocLIST     # >> /tmp/www/wlan.html
  sleep 10;
done;
```

I would like it to output like so:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "IP": "192.168.1.55",
        "MAC": "01:81:18:3d:49:5e",
        "HOST": "DavidsAndroidPhone"
    }, {
        "IP": "192.168.1.79",
        "MAC": "04:10:87:8c:47:9a",
        "HOST": "BobsIphone"
    }]
}
```

Could anyone help me out in modifying my first script I posted to include the **IP** and **NAME**?

**UPDATE**

When I do the command **arp** in PuTTYtel I get the following info:

```
DD-WRT login: root
Password:
==========================================================

     ___  ___     _      _____  ______       ____  ___
    / _ \/ _ \___| | /| / / _ \/_  __/ _  __|_  / / _ \
   / // / // /___/ |/ |/ / , _/ / /   | |/ //_ <_/ // /
  /____/____/    |__/|__/_/|_| /_/    |___/____(_)___/

                       DD-WRT v3.0
                   http://www.dd-wrt.com

==========================================================


BusyBox v1.24.1 (2016-03-07 05:09:22 CET) built-in shell (ash)

root@DD-WRT:~# arp
android-17af243062d3eb6b (192.168.1.144) at 00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c [ether]  on br0
```

So currently the script I am running (getmac.sh) looks at this and gets only this:

```
{ 00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c, }
```

So given that, how can I modify the script to get more of the information I am looking for in the proper JSON layout?

**UPDATE 2**

Ok I have this code here:

```
arp | awk 'BEGIN { print "{" } { print "MAC:" $4 ", IP:" $2 ", HOST:" $1} END { print "}" }'
```

Which outputs the following:

```
{
MAC:00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c, IP:(192.168.1.144), HOST:android-17af243062d3eb6b
}
```

Now given that above, how can I remove the **(** and the **)** from the IP and format it in proper JSON form? I've tried **awk -F'('** but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Uh, why are you generating the script every time? Your question would be much simpler to answer if you just posted the generated script, regardless.

Comment: The script from the site would generate a file `/tmp/www/wlan.html` if you uncommented those lines.

Comment: ... Though it's a tad clumsy with the temp file. Without sample output from `wl assoclist` and `getleases` it's not really clear what it's doing.

Comment: @tripleee Running *wl assoclist* gives me no output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your current script contains an incredible amount of cruft. It could be refactored to just

```
arp | awk 'BEGIN { print "{" } { print toupper($4) } END { print "}" }'
```

Without access to the output from `dumpleases` we can't really tell you how to add the IP address resolution, but `arp -n` on many Linuxes returns the IP address in `$1`, and you get the resolved address (if any) without `-n`.  But looking at the script from the web site, all you want is probably really `dumpleases`.  The script from the web site could be refactored to

```
while true  # fix silly [ 1 ]
do
  wl assoclist | awk '{print tolower($2)}' > /tmp/assocLIST
  dumpleases | awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]++; next }
      $2 in a { print s "{"; print "\"Hostname\": \"" $1 "\";
         gsub("()", "", $2); print "\"MAC\": "\""" $2 "\"";
         print "\"IP\": \"" $3 "\""; print "}"; s=",\n" }' /tmp/assocLIST -
done
```

and if you don't care about the `wl assoclist` part or the endless loop, all you seem to need is to refactor the `dumpleases` output to JSON.  That's the part after `$2 in a` in the script above.  (I assumed the MAC address is what `wl assoclist` produces; without output samples, I just have to guess a lot of things here.)

---

As for generating the script on the fly, that's just silly.  Anything that (I am guessing a bit here again) looks like

```
ssh busybox "echo 'echo moo' >/tmp/script
    chmod +x /tmp/script
    /tmp/script"
```

could be rewritten without any loss of functionality as just

```
ssh busybox 'echo moo'
```

(and for what it's worth, if the script wasn't so useless, I would definitely recommend rewriting it to use a here document instead).

Comment: for the **while true** it continuously says **could not open input file: No such file or directory**

Comment: Did you forget the shebang, or did you put a non-breaking space?

Comment: See update now for proper JSON quotes and trimmed parens from the IP address field.

Comment: would you mind modifying your answer to show hoe to put that info into a html page that can be called?

Comment: That's a too broad requirement to easily fit into this question.  I'm guessing you are asking about CGI but this is probably best covered in a new, separate question with detailed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If interested in a JSON formated version:

*for this DD-WRT arp format:*

```
root@myrouter:~# arp
myhost1.mysite.com (192.168.2.12) at 08:0b:05:04:08:04 [ether]  on br0 
myhost2.mysite.com (192.168.2.21) at 18:1b:15:14:18:14 [ether]  on br0 ...
```

*The following command:*

```
arp | awk 'BEGIN { print "[" } {gsub(/[\(\)]/,""); print "  {\"MAC\": \"" $4 "\",\n   \"IP\": \"" $2 "\",\n   \"Address\": \"" $1 "\",\n   \"Iface\": \"" $7 "\"},"} END { print "]" }'
```

*Returns:*

```
[
  {"MAC": "08:0b:05:04:08:04",
   "IP": "192.168.10.12",
   "Address": "myhost1.mysite.com",
   "Iface": "br0"},
  {"MAC": "18:1b:15:14:18:14",
   "IP": "192.168.10.21",
   "Address": "myhost2.mysite.com",
   "Iface": "br0"},
]
```